# IntelliJ Idea red Spring and Lombok annotations

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a problem with IntelliJ Idea 2020.1 Ultimate Edition. It shows Lombok and Spring annotations and imports in red. The project compiles, I can run tests. I did some googling. I tried to reimport maven projects and go to File->Invalidate Caches/Restart. Then I deleted Idea [system directory](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) - it does not help. Before it worked fine, I do not know why it started doing this. Can somebody help me out?
[image: red imports]

Comment: Do you have Lombok plug-in installed? If the issue persists, please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have Lombok plugin installed. How can I provide a Verifiable example of an IDEA glitch? I have no idea how to reproduce it exactly like that on other machine. If I give you a piece of code, most likely it will work fine in your IDE

Comment: Delete .idea directory from the project, reimport the project from Gradle/Maven. If it doesn't help, share the logs (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data). It may be better to proceed at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA where you can share the files privately with JetBrains team.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is a correct solution, but it worked for me. I just reinstalled IDEA. It was faster that talk to IDEA support trying to figure out what is the cause of the issue

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and fixed it from this way. [First download lombok dependency from spring.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uLHW.png)

Then go to IDE and paste it to pom file and run. It isn't fix your problem. Go to [Choose this and clear cache. Then restart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gasY1.png)

If isn't fix your problem then go to this site and download relevant version of lombok for your IDE. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDyJ8.png)

Then it will download a file. Then go to where you install the IDE and go to this path and paste that lombok java file.
[IDE path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok9o9.png)

After trying these methods error was fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The above IntelliJ was resolved after installing the Lombook plugin in the IDE, which should probably resolve your issue.

[image]